# mysql - filter query result based on count of one column's value?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I am running the following mysql query:

```
SELECT visitnum, userid
FROM user_visit 
WHERE date >= '2015-10-31 00:00:00' AND date <= '2015-11-01 23:59:59'
```

Which returns me the following results:

```
visitnum   userid
2010       60265
2011       60264
2012       60264
2013       60268
2014       60269
2015       60269
2016       60269
```

As you can see, this means the user 60265 and 60268 has one visit; user 60264 has two visits and user 60269 has three visits.

Now - how do I modify my mysql query so that it returns me only the rows associated with users that only visit ONCE? In other words, I expect my query to return me the following result:

```
    visitnum   userid
    2010       60265
    2013       60268
```

And how do I modify the query to return me only the rows that associated with users that only visit TWICE? like this:

```
 visitnum   userid
 2011       60264
 2012       60264
```

Comment: If you OUTER JOIN on one thing equals another thing while yet one other thing doesn't equal something else, those with NULL results will be just what you're after.

Comment: @Strawberry Not exactly sure about what you meant. Could you give some more details maybe through an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT visitnum, userid
FROM user_visit
WHERE userid IN (
    SELECT userid
    FROM user_visit 
    WHERE date >= '2015-10-31 00:00:00' AND date <= '2015-11-01 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

Comment: Thanks but this only returns me one row like userid = 60264 and 
COUNT(*) = 2. What I really want are two rows with different visitnum values and same userid values as I mentioned in my question. Is there a way to further modify your query to make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick:

```
SELECT max(visitnum) as visitnum, userid
FROM user_visit 
WHERE date >= '2015-10-31 00:00:00' AND date <= '2015-11-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY usserid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

The trick here is that `MAX(visitnum)` is the one-and-only visit number, when there is only one row in the group.

An alternative way that doesn't use `GROUP BY` is:

```
select uv.*
from user_visits uv
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_visits uv2
                  where uv2.userid = uv.userid and uv.visitnum <> uv2.visitnum
                 );
```

This should have better performance, if you have in an index on `user_visits(userid, visitnum)`.